# Memory leakage threat on vmware esx that runs on server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-esx, memory-leak

I run ESX on server 2003 with two virtual machines (A and B).
Suppose that "A" uses a chunk of physical memory. After I shutdown the virtual machine "A", what happens to the data of "A" in the RAM of the server?
I know that the OS marks that space as "available to use" but my concern is that a process in "B" will asks for some memory space, get the chunk that was released by "A", and will be able to read the data that "A" left there ("A" left confidential data).
Are my concerns legitimate?
How would you recommend to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

According to [*Understanding Memory Resource Management in VMWare ESX Server*](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/perf-vsphere-memory_management.pdf), and I quote -

> In order to avoid information leaking among virtual machines, the 
>   hypervisor always writes zeroes to the host physical memory before
>   assigning it to a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing anything, since this is a non-issue for ESX.

ESX implements its memory manager like all modern operating systems do, in that each process gets a virtual memory space onto which physical pages are mapped as needed. When a process ends, the pages associated with that process are returned to the Free pool. When a process needs another page, it is pulled from the Free pool and written to. A process attempting to read unallocated pages will just get zeros or crash out (I'm not sure how ESX handles this, but either way you won't get random physical pages).

Mind, this is all at the ESX level. All Machine B sees are pages allocated to it by the ESX-level VMM, it'll never see anything at all from Machine A.

Comment: Is there any way to "scramble" the data in the free pool? I'm worried about malicious code in "B" that scans the free pool for left overs from "A".
The data is not deleted, the memory space is only marked as "available to future use".

Comment: @Spivi I think you misunderstood the allocation process. A physical page is mapped to virtual memory *when it is written to*. A malicious process on B has **no way** to *directly* access the physical memory on the host system, which is the only way to get at the leftovers of Machine A. Virtual Memory isolation has been a feature for Operating System for ages, and the Linux kernel (upon which ESX is based) has had it since before version 1.0.